# Calculations on the Server side with Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, class

I am trying the do my calculations on the Server side with Ajax.

The data is put back into Default.aspx thru jQuery, Ajax and Javascript.

I am using Classes to send the data from the webmethod function back to jQuery and the resultant of the Ajax code.

The input to the WebMethod Function s thru Json data.

The output of the ajax webmethod function is not printing out.

Not certain where the error is coming from:

1-XML in calculations

```
Dim xmldoc0 = XDocument.Load("xml/file1.xml")
```

The function would not accept:

```
Dim xmldoc0 = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xml/file1.xml"))
```

2-Ajax mechanics

```
Public Class planetClass
    Public Property p1() As Double
        Get
            Return pl1
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            pl1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private pl1 As Double
    Public Property p2() As Double
        Get
           Return pl2
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
           pl2 = value
         End Set
     End Property
     Private pl2 As Double
     Public Property p3() As Double
        Get
            Return pl3
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            pl3 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private pl3 As Double
End Class
```

Default.aspx

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {                
            var data = { mo: '3', dy: '20', yr: '2017' };
            var json1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: json1,
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(result[0].p1);
                    $("#<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>").val(result[0].p2);
                    $("#<%= TextBox3.ClientID%>").val(result[0].p3);
                    $("#<%= TextBox4.ClientID%>").val(result[1].p1);
                    $("#<%= TextBox5.ClientID%>").val(result[1].p2);
                    $("#<%= TextBox6.ClientID%>").val(result[1].p3);
                },
                error: function (status, ex) {
                    alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function fn1(ByVal mo As Double, ByVal dy As Double, ByVal yr As Double) As String
    Dim planetList As New List(Of planetClass)()
'...calculations....
    Dim ca As New planetClass()
    ca.p1 = Convert.ToDouble(a(1))
    ca.p2 = Convert.ToDouble(a(2))
    ca.p3 = Convert.ToDouble(a(3))
    planetList.Add(ca)
    Dim ce As New planetClass()
    ce.p1 = Convert.ToDouble(ecc(1))
    ce.p2 = Convert.ToDouble(ecc(2))
    ce.p3 = Convert.ToDouble(ecc(3))

    Dim serializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    fn1 = serializer.Serialize(planetList)
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(result);` ?

Comment: my first guess is issues in default.aspx.  can you post the rendered `ready` function, that is to say with the TextBox1.ClientID as it's value.  Usually I find that results are not getting put where expected.

Comment: Error Code:Status:[object Object] Ex: error

Comment: inspect that status object.  likely, `status.responseText` in your error handler contains the clue you have been looking for.